# getting null values in formData in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello all I am facing some issues while using react functional components hooks with formData i am getting null data in formData i am using usestate hooks but i am getting balnk array as output

```
const [profilestate, setProfileState] = useState({
        dob:"",
        city:"",
        state:"",
        country:"",
        school: "",
        board: "",
        age: "",
        gender: "",
        degree_college: "",
        masters_college: "",
        organizations: "",
        department: "",
        title: "",
        profile_image:""
});

const handleChange = (e) => {
        setProfileState({
            ...profilestate,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
}
const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        setProfileState({
            ...profilestate,
            profile_image: e.target.files[0]
        })
}
    
const { dob, state, city, country, school, board, age, gender, degree_college, masters_college, organizations, department, title, profile_image } = profilestate;
        
const formdata = new FormData();
         
formdata.append('dob', dob);
formdata.append('city', city);
formdata.append('state', state);
formdata.append('country', country);
formdata.append('school', school);
formdata.append('board', board);
formdata.append('age', age);
formdata.append('gender', gender);
formdata.append('degree_college', degree_college);
formdata.append('masters_college', masters_college);
formdata.append('organizations', organizations);
formdata.append('department', department);
formdata.append('title', title);
formdata.append('profile_image', profile_image);

const response = await fetch(Constants.url + 'auth/addUserDetail', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))}`
            },
         body: formdata
       });
const result = await response.json();
       if (result.status === 'success') {
            hideLoader()
           toast.success(result.message);
       }
        else {
            hideLoader()
            toast.error(result.message);
             return false;
        }
```

anyone can help me out in this i am getting data as null array i am using formData in hooks any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the formData outside of any function, this would initialize the formData with the initial value of your state i.e. profileState which is empty strings. Initialising formData with empty string results in undefined or null values.

So you should wrap the entire formData part that is outside any function into another single function like handleSubmition which will be triggered when the user upload any form from your component.

```js
const handleSubmition = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formdata = new FormData();

  formdata.append('dob', dob);
  formdata.append('city', city);
  formdata.append('state', state);
  formdata.append('country', country);
  formdata.append('school', school);
  formdata.append('board', board);
  formdata.append('age', age);
  formdata.append('gender', gender);
  formdata.append('degree_college', degree_college);
  formdata.append('masters_college', masters_college);
  formdata.append('organizations', organizations);
  formdata.append('department', department);
  formdata.append('title', title);
  formdata.append('profile_image', profile_image);

  const response = await fetch(Constants.url + 'auth/addUserDetail', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))}`
    },
    body: formdata
  });
  const result = await response.json();
  if (result.status === 'success') {
    hideLoader()
    toast.success(result.message);
  } else {
    hideLoader()
    toast.error(result.message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const addUser= async ()=>{
        const api_url = Constants.url + 'auth/addUserDetail';
        const config = {
         headers: {
           contentType: 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))}`
           
          }
        }
        const response = await axios.post(url, {...profilestate},config);
        console.log(response.data); //get the response
        /* do rest of stuff */
}
```

No need to use the form data at all. Api just expect the form body in form of object that you can easily send via **axios**.  You already have local state object that contains all the data. I hope the above idea would help you to figure out and simplify the problem.